# HTML email not centering

Tags: html-email

the HTML looks good in a web browser. The header is centered and the text is indented slightly left and right and centered under the header.
The method I'm using to send an email is open it in the web browser> select all> Paste into Outlook.
Everything justifies left.
(before/after image attached)
This forum will not let me paste the code (it's telling me to indent 4 spaces. I have no idea what that means) so here's a link to the HTML file. [Capital-Images-email-sig.html](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ku054pxnc9lpfcr/Capital-Images-email-sig.html?dl=0)Sorry for the hassle.

I am not a coder so any and all help very much appreciated.
This was together from a patchwork of a few sources so it's probably sloppy.

Thank you so much!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2QoP.jpg)

Comment: If you copy the code in, then select it, and then click the {} button, it will format it correctly as code (by adding the 4 spaces). "Indent 4 spaces" means add 4 spaces to the start of each line.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please paste your code in your question and do not link to a third party resource. If you delete that file from your dropbox some months in the future, the question becomes worthless for the next user searching for a solution for the same problem.